# didReceiveMemoryWarning app crashing

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks, didreceivememorywarning

I am trying to write my didReceiveMemoryWarning method. 
Should I simply set my IBOutlets to nil like in my ViewDidUnload?

I am simulating a memory warning on the iPhone Simulator, but the second time I run it, the app crashes.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

self.repCount=nil;
self.weight=nil;
self.repUp=nil;
self.repDown=nil;
self.weightUp=nil;
self.weightDown=nil;
self.next=nil;
self.weightLabel=nil;
self.titleLabel=nil;
self.repLabel=nil;

[super viewDidUnload];

}
```

Any help or direction is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You mean the second time you simulate a memory warning, right?

Comment: yes, the second time I simulate a memory warning the app crashes.

Comment: What does the error say? can you produce some details on that? I don't see a problem with the code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UIViewController will unload its view in response to a memory warning if its view is not visible. Since you're not overriding the behavior of `-didReceiveMemoryWarning` you shouldn't need to do anything in that method. Just allow the view controller to behave normally.

Your app's crash is therefore due to some other problem and you have not provided enough information to determine what that might be.

Comment: Thanks got the crash figured out too. IS it required override didReceiveMemoryWarning? I am having a hard time figuring out what I should be releasing...

Comment: No, overriding didReceiveMemoryWarning is optional. But if you do, you'll have to call super.